# Why do I need to Instantiate an Object Array Twice?

Tags: c#

I have created an Object array like this. But to assign value to object, I have to instantiate each object at every positions of the array? Why do I need this?

This is My method

```
 StageObject[] StageSplitDate = new StageObject[Stages.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < Stages.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                StageSplitDate[i] = new StageObject();
                StageSplitDate[i].StageId = "String Value";
                StageSplitDate[i].FromTime = StartTime;
                StartTime =StartTime.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(10));
                StageSplitDate[i].ToTime = StartTime;
            }
            return StageSplitDate;
```

And Object Class

```
 public class StageObject
    {
        public string StageId { get; set; }
        public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The first step, defining the array, allocates enough memory for the array to hold the elements.  The next step, assigns the actually value to a position in the array.  Until you assign a value to a position in the array, it has no value, it is null.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is **C#** tagged here? (O_o)

Comment: @R.J, more like why Java, unless it now has a Convert.ToDouble method.

Comment: @MadProgrammer More to the point, it doesn't (or shouldn't) allocate the memory for the elements of the array. They should just be null pointers until each element is allocated with `new`

Comment: @RyanAmos True, the use of "allocate memory" is a open to interruption, but it does need to allocate "space" for the pointers to be stored.  It DOES NOT allocate memory for the objects, that comes later.

Comment: c# tagged bcoz it was written in c# and tagged java since both codes seems to be same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to instantiate each object at every positions of the array?

You are not instantiating the array elements twice. In the first line you instantiated an array `StageSplitDate`  with every element set to null.**By default each array *(of reference types)* element is initialized to null.** To use it further you need to instantiate each object in the array as well, otherwise you will get null reference exception.

**For C#**

[Arrays (C# Programming Guide) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

The default value of numeric array elements are set to zero, and **reference elements are set to null**.

*(Since the question was originally tagged for java)*

**For JAVA**

[4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)

> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10):
> - For **all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null**.

Comment: But while creating the array all objects in the array are defined. An array cannot have different Datatypes. Then why should we initialize it for each object. Isn't it well defined while declaring the array itself???

Comment: @SubinJacob, thats the way the language designer's choose it, now think if there is a requirement to instantiate an object with some default values, *(for example- default constructor is missing, instead the constructor requires some parameters)*, how would you do that then.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is an array of `StageObject` *references*. The `StageObject`s themselves don't exist yet. Essentially each entry in the array merely "points" to or "refers" to a `StageObject`.

Before you call `new StageObject()`, each array element is `null`, meaning it's referring to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Think of an analogy where an array is a bookshelf. If you want a shelf of books, just buying the shelf is only the first step; you then need to buy each book and put it on the shelf. Same idea here: allocating the array gives you an empty container, and then you need to create each object and put it into the container.

Why is it like this? Because an initially-empty array is often what you want -- and even if it isn't, unless your object only has a no-arg constructor, Java wouldn't even know how to construct each object.

Comment: But while creating the array all objects in the array are defined. An array cannot have different Datatypes. Then why should we initialize it for each object. Isn't it well defined while declaring the array itself???

Comment: No, what's defined are a bunch of slots for array references. It's up to you to assign values to those slots.

Answer (score 1):

> StageObject[] StageSplitDate = new StageObject[Stages.Rows.Count];

The above statement only makes reference array for `StageObject` which are intialized with null but does not actually initanstiate the objects of `StageObject`

> StageSplitDate[i] = new StageObject();

The above statement is creating object of type `StageObject` and assigns the reference to `StageSplitDate` element

Answer (score 1):

`new StageObject[Stages.Rows.Count]` creates a new array of `StageObject` references containing `Stages.Rows.Count` null references. You want each element to point to a `StageObject`. To do that, you need to create some `StageObject` instances.